# Can I use .aspx extension for Google Sitemap?

Tags: seo, sitemap

I am creating a google sitemap in Umbraco but the output is .aspx. Is this ok to use with google?

Thanks

Comment: add "rewrite rule" sitemap.aspx -> sitem.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you use the correct mimetype, probably yes.

Also, the comment of Userpassword about use "rewrite rule" could be another way to do it.